# Remove source code

Tags: truffle, bytecode

I am designing a smart contract *challenge/enigma* where I expect participants to run a given function of the contract to find the "secret treasure".

I use truffle to compile the contract, then `truffle migrate`, then run a truffle console, and participants get a prompt in that console.

The problem is that, currently, they can **directly view the source code** of my contract doing `mycontract.source`, and hence they read the source code and immediately find the treasure.

I would like to **remove the source code**. (It's okay if they see other information, but source code really spoils it too much).

**Attempt #1**. When I compile the source code, compiled artificats go to `./build/contracts/mycontract.json`. I have edited this file to remove:

`"source": "pragma soldity ^0.4.18;\n\ncontract mycontract{...}"`

Unfortunately, that modification is not taken into account, and I continue to see the full source code for my contract :(

**Attempt #2**. In another attempt, I have tried to modify the `mycontract.sol` after compilation in case source code was read from there, but no, same, my source code continues to be fully visible.

How can I do this?

Comment: Blockchain is supposed to be completely public. Taking this into account, source code must be public, or it defeats the purpose of blockchain.

Comment: Encryption? Not necessarily the best way to use a contract though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [web3](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#deploy) to deploy contract. It will take ABI and bytecode as an argument. There will be no need to specify source code to deploy it.

Refer web3 documentation: 
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#deploy

Comment: I have no web3.eth.Contract.deploy() ... ```truffle(development)> web3.eth.contract.
web3.eth.contract.propertyIsEnumerable  web3.eth.contract.toLocaleString
web3.eth.contract.toString              web3.eth.contract.valueOf
```
web3.eth.contract.apply                 web3.eth.contract.arguments
web3.eth.contract.bind                  web3.eth.contract.call
web3.eth.contract.caller                web3.eth.contract.length
web3.eth.contract.name                  

web3.eth.contract.prototype

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found consists in adding a script to run at the end of migrations (`./migrations/9_source.js`), where this script edits the `.source` field of my smart contract:

```
let mycontract = artifacts.require("./mycontract.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
    mycontract.source = web3.toHex(mycountract.source);
}
```

Then, run `truffle migrate` and `truffle console` and `mycontract.source` will have encoded value for source code instead of "readable" source code.